# Sandisk usb stick wont show up on computer

Tags: usb

new here. Still getting used to using ubuntu this is my first attempt at the operating system. I have a usb Sandisk 16Gb drive. It appears on my tv when i put it in but will not appear on my laptop. This has stumped me and is really stressing me out. And help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: After plugging in your flash drive to your laptop, please edit your question to include the output of the commands `sudo fdisk -l` and `mount | grep /dev/sd`.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a program in the Ubuntu Software Center, named **Disks** and install it. I've had the same problem with a few of my USB sticks, but **Disks** has always found them.

They may not mount automatically, but you can mount them in, **Disks** simply by clicking the **Play** button in the program's interface.